# Как убрать вывод изображений с помощью счетчика в определенном промежутке

Tags: php

Сейчас вывод изображений осуществляется с помощью счетчика в 3 промежутках:

```
0-73
73-88
88-141
```

Вопрос: Как убрать вывод изображений с помощью счетчика в промежутке 0-73?

```
$name = glob('./album/*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE);

$counter = 0; //заводим счетчик
for($i=0; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) {
  if( substr($name[$i][2],0,1) != "_") {
    echo "<li><img src='".$dir."img/_share/".$shortname."_1.jpg' height='162px'></li>";

$counter++;

    if ($counter == 73) {
echo "<li><img src='".$dir."img/_share/".$shortname."_1.jpg' height='162px'></li>";
} elseif ($counter == 88) {
     require_once "ddd.php";
} elseif ($counter == 141) {
   break;     
} 


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `continue`:

```
$counter = 0; //заводим счетчик
for ( $i = 0; $i <= ( sizeof( $name ) - 1 ); $i++ ) {

    if ( substr( $name[ $i ][ 2 ], 0, 1 ) != "_" ) {

        $counter++;

    /*Условие */
    if($counter < 73){
        continue;
    }

        echo "<li><img src='" . $dir . "img/_share/" . $shortname . "_1.jpg' height='162px'></li>";



        if ( $counter == 73 ) {
            echo "<li><img src='" . $dir . "img/_share/" . $shortname . "_1.jpg' height='162px'></li>";
        } elseif ( $counter == 88 ) {
            require_once "ddd.php";
        } elseif ( $counter == 141 ) {
            break;
        }


    }
}
```